# python patch : how to apply

Tags: python, patch, ubuntu-12.04

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS; python 2.7.3 is pre-installed.
A bug in python 2.7 distribution has been fixed in their repository.
changeset 76420:ab9d6c4907e7 2.7
How do I apply this patch on my PC ?

Thanks,

Vineet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mercurial equivalents of following comands:

1. svn log
2. svn diff
3. patch

The "hg" equivalents of the first two commands will identify all the files that have changed and the the changes in them. The last command will apply the patches.

Use the man command to get detailed usage information on the commands.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are running a custom-compiled version of Python that you pulled from the `cvs` server (which I'm pretty sure you are not), the best thing to do is to wait until an official build is provided by the Ubuntu packagers. Also, since this bug was found on Apr 19, 2012 and hasn't been bundled into Python 2.7's tarball, it isn't a critical bug.

In short, either compile Python from the repository (not recommended), patch the Python library files yourself (they're just Python files, but I wouldn't edit them), or just put up with this cryptic bug that doesn't really affect anyone.

I wouldn't worry about it. If it was critical, Python 2.7.4 would've been released with this patch.

Comment: Thanks for your input. But this bug is related to threading. In a multi-threaded environment, it would cause problem. Won't it?

Comment: No, it relates to a really specific corner-case of a `DummyThread` object not being handled properly. I've never seen one for as long as I've used Python.